# Select2 is not sending remote parameters

Tags: jquery, jquery-select2

I am trying to send to parameters to one servlet, but I can't do it's works,
always I receive "null".
I found some examples around the web, but none work for me.
Could someone give me some idea why is not working?
Here my code:

```
        $('#cboCli').empty();
        $('#cboCli').select2({
            theme: "bootstrap",
            width: "100%"
        });
        $('#cboCli').append("<option>Cargando ...</option>");
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "Cuenta",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            data: function (term, action,tipocuen) {
                return {
                    action: 'BUSCACONSULTA',
                    tipocuen: $("#cboTipoCue").val(),
                    term: term
                };
            },                
            success: function (data) {
                $('#cboCli').empty();
                $.each(data.aaData, function (i, data) {
                    $('#cboCli').append('<option value="' + data.id + '">' + data.nombre + '</option>');
                });
            },
            error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                alert("Ocurrio un Error: " + XMLHttpRequest.responseText);
            }
        });
```

The parameters "action" and "tipocuen", never arrive to my servlet!
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`data` parameter for `$.ajax` is wrong. As stated in [jQuery api document](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/), data must be a `PlainObject`, `String` or `Array`.

Change it like the following:

```
data: {
     action: 'BUSCACONSULTA',
     tipocuen: $("#cboTipoCue").val(),
     term: term
},
```

And I think this has nothing to do with `jquery-select2`.

If you want to send params correctly, I think you should bind `$.ajax` to some event.